# How can I automate my workflow of transferring data?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, automation

My machine is situated on `Domain A`. The main database for my system resides on `Domain B`. To get some data from the database, I do the following:

- Initiate a remote desktop connection to a machine in `Domain B`
- Use a SQL query to dump data locally on the machine in `Domain B`
- Mount my local drive onto the machine in `Domain B` and copy the generated files
- Import the data into my local database on my machine in `Domain A`

While I don't really have a problem with this, I am finding myself do the same thing over and over again and am looking for a way to automate this. Unfortunately, the remote machine in `Domain B` logs me out after a period of inactivity of 15 minutes so I cannot mount my drive and copy the data directly onto it. My goal is this:

> Be able to transfer data from the database in `Domain B` into the
>   database I have setup locally in `Domain A`.

Is there anyway to automate (or at least partially automate) this tedious process? All I want to do is to mirror some data from the remote database but the whole import/export process is sucking the energy out of me because I always face some or the other import errors. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I only have read-access to the databases in `Domain B`. The machine in `Domain B` can pull data from other linked server as well situated in the same domain.

Comment: Have you considered using a Linked Server Object  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Comment: @John Hartsock: Thank You. I tried adding it but it complains with: `Could not open a connection to SQL Server[53] OLE DB Provider 'SQLNCLI10' for linked server "<SERVERNAME>" returned message "Login timeout expired"`. I am guessing this is because the server does not allow connections from a remote domain perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not build an SSIS package that you can execute that will pull the data from Domain B and plug it into the database on Domain A?

Comment: Hmm... Do you mean use the Import/Export Wizard to create the SSIS Package?

Comment: I meant open Business Intelligence Development Studio and build an SSIS package. I don't think that the Import/Export Wizard would be flexible enough to do what it looks like you need.

Comment: While I am not exactly sure how to do this, reading more on this makes me feel that this is indeed the way to go in the long-term. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are able to mount the disk of machine at Domain A to machine at Domain B, I suppose you are able to connect from A to B?

In that case, how about doing a remote SQL connection to domain B from domain A? Then you could dump data straight to your local disk and import to database.

Comment: I did consider this. The database in `Domain B` does not seem to allow connections from any client which is not in `Domain B`. This is the reason I was not able to do a remote SQL connection either.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to automate many of these steps using Automation Anywhere. By using either the recorder or the editor, you can set up these steps and then run them anytime with the scheduler.
Affordable as well.
Hope this helps.
Tom